# Passing next argument to 'STDIN'

Tags: ruby, popen3

I am using open3 to pass `STDIN` to a program, and then read and parse `STDOUT`. My program expects an argument in the form of `e0`, `e1 e2`, etc.

Everytime a new argument is given, the `STDOUT` changes. I don't know how to pass the next argument after parsing the first result which will give the next number to pass as an argument. Here is my code:

```
require 'open3'
require 'state_machines'

#this is for the first command  e0 only 

cmd = ('./pos.tx')
status1 = ''

puts "Step 1: #{cmd}"
Open3.pipeline_rw(cmd) {|stdin, stdout, wait_thrs|
  stdin.write "e0\n"
  stdin.close 
  #
  status1 = stdout.read  
  lines3 = status1.match(/Ee\s+(.*)\s+/)
    @next_states = status1.match(/\d+/)
    event = status1.match(/\s+\D+\s+\n/)

    #puts lines3
    puts @next_states
    puts event
}
```

The next argument is stored in `@next_states`, and can be one number or many numbers. How can I use the elements of this array to continue to the next part of the program and parse again?